# is there a time you would ever need an abstract class without any abstract methods

Tags: java, methods, abstract

I am playing around with abstract methods and classes...is there a time you would ever need something like this instead of just creating a concrete class ?

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{

    public String nonAbstractMethodOne(String param1,String param2){
        String param = param1 + param2;
        return param;
    }

    public static void nonAbstractMethodTwo(String param){
        System.out.println("Value of param is "+param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if you wanted common behaviour for all concrete derived classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract classes can provide *default* implementations.

Consider the `MouseListener` in the Java API, and the corresponding abstract class `MouseAdapter`.

Using "pure" (non-abstract) `MouseAdapter` does not make sense: all methods are implemented as no-ops. However, the class is very convenient to use as abstract parent for a concrete listener, because you only have to *override* the one method that you are interested in, instead of having to reimplemet lots of methods as no-ops.

It's not necessary to make `MouseAdapter` abstract. It is a complete class. It just doesn't make *sense* to use it without overriding at least one method. But otherwise, you would need to have `MouseListenerWithoutMouseClicked`, if you wanted it to have at least one `abstract` method.

Another example would be the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). The interface defines the actual API. The abstract class would implement (some or all) transition functions as the *default operation*. Each state would only override those methods, where it diverts from the default behavior.

In general, any "abstract" method declaration *could* (and often: should) be moved to an interface instead. The only reason why I often declare them as `@Override abstract` nevertheless is documentation purposes, to emphasize which methods need to be implemented for a concrete instance.
Any method inherited from an interface will be effectively declare an abstract method.

Comment: abstract class in some cases works nice ,but still interfaces are much better due to components' isolation from each other.

Comment: Additionally, even in cases where it may occasionally be useful to have an instance with just default behavior, it may be cleaner to have a sealed type defined for just that purpose, especially if such a thing would make the most sense as a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this but i would argue against it. Class hierarchies are very inflexible, and since this code doesn't take advantage of abstract methods I would look for an alternative way to implement this.

The point of the abstract class is that it provides a template where the superclass defines abstract methods and calls them in its own methods, so the subclasses specify how the details happen. Nothing about this example requires inheritance, so I would do without it.

The [example Bohemian brings up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20819115/217324) is that of the adapter class, which is a convenience that provides default implementations of multiple methods so the class that you write doesn't have to provide implementations of methods that you don't care about anyway. That would be the best time to have an abstract class without abstract methods (although whether the adapter is abstract doesn't really matter that much).

Comment: And definition of  non abstract methods in abstract class provides some default functionality for every class which extends it.

Comment: @solvator: yes, but there's no good reason to extend the abstract class here, you'd be as well off using an interface and a default implementation.

Comment: In this case, it's true. I more prefer to use interfaces

Answer (score 2):

When you want to provide default implementations for methods that subclasses should override. Particularly when the default implementation is "do nothing" or that owns an "unimplemented" exception.

An example from the JDK is [`HttpServet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html), which has methods to handle each of the four http methods (get, post, put and delete) whose default implementations throw a `ServletException` , forcing the subclass to override those methods they want to implement, but only those. Methods not implemented explode if called. This makes good sense, because it cleanly throws an exception if a web client hits the server with an unexpected web method.